# How to synchronize view table to manual temporary table?

Tags: mysql

I have tables in database that consist of so many data records. I made view tables because I joined the tables. Then, when I tried to open the view tables, the time took so long because the tables had many data. So, I decided to make temporary table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE temp_ AS (SELECT * FROM view)
```

then, I want to synchronize the view and temporary table. As the example, when I tried to update the view table, then we're able to know that the temporary table has to change too because the temporary is synchronized with the view table. Maybe, it can be solved when the view's updated time > generated time than we have to update the table

I have table like this

[image]

[image]

I manually inserted the data records to both of that table. What may I do to synchronize them? Thanks in advance